# if within an if

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

im having a slight problem putting `if` statements inside `if` statments e.g:

```
<?php
$steponeimage = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'step_one_image', true);
$steponecontent = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'step_one_content', true);
$steptwoimage = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'step_two_image', true);
$steptwocontent = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'step_two_content', true);
$stepthreeimage = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'step_three_image', true);
$stepthreecontent = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'step_3_content', true);
if ($steponecontent) {
?>
<div id="processPanel" class="panel">
    <a href="#content1" label="1">Step 1</a>
<?php if ($steptwocontent) { ?>
<a href="#content2" label="2">Step Two</a>
<?php } else { ?><?php } ?>
<?php if ($stepthreecontent) { ?>
<a href="#content3" label="3">Step Three</a>
<?php } else { ?><?php } ?>
    <div id="content1">
<p><?php $images1 = $helper->imageDisplay($steponeimage , $height , $width , true , $ar[0] , false, false,'' ,'' ,false);
echo "<div class='imageholder'> $images1 </div>"; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $steponecontent; ?></p>
</div>
<?php if ($steptwocontent); { ?>
<div id="content2">
<p><?php $images2 = $helper->imageDisplay($steptwoimage , $height , $width , true , $ar[0] , false, false,'' ,'' ,false);
echo "<div class='imageholder'> $images2 </div>"; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $steptwocontent; ?></p>
</div><?php } else { ?><?php } ?>
<?php if ($stepthreecontent); { ?>
<div id="content3">
<p><?php $images3 = $helper->imageDisplay($stepthreeimage , $height , $width , true , $ar[0] , false, false,'' ,'' ,false);
echo "<div class='imageholder'> $images3 </div>"; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $stepthreecontent; ?></p>
</div><?php } else { ?><?php } ?>
</div>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Im trying to read post meta data from a wordpress post and if there is a step one meta box filled in it shows the step by step information then if step two's meta box is filled in the it add's step two there and if step three's box is filled it it add's step three etc.

my error is

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE

this is coming from here:

```
<p><?php echo $steptwocontent; ?></p>
</div><?php } else { ?><?php } ?>
```

Comment: Syntax error: too localized for SO. Also you should just indent your code sensefully, then such issues become easier to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
if ($steptwocontent); {
```

Change it to

```
if ($steptwocontent) {
```

EDIT:

just noticed you did the same thing with stepthreecontent too

Change

```
if ($stepthreecontent); {
```

to

```
if ($stepthreecontent) {
```